# Is it possible to list all of the $refs attribute from Vue global components?

Tags: vue.js

I'm about to create a UI that let the user to grab their component value in another component by it's `$refs` attribute which is dynamically generated with it's given name & UUID.

I want it to be listed on a table and the user would be able to select which `$refs` that its value to be used, in this case, in the query builder. So that when the user click one of the references, it copying its value to the code playground as parameter.

Please take a look at this image:

> The content inside the red circle is the `refs` list, it's not limited to input, it can be a table, or something with default values. And the blue one is the database `columns` which is shown after the user selected a table in their database. The arrows is to illustrate what happen when the user click on one of it.

[image: SQL Playground UI]

Is it possible to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you only want to move data from one child component to another, there are easier ways to do that. You can have the state in parent and pass it to both components with props or use state management system like vuex.

Comment: well, it gonna be a huge changes about how I developed all those things from scratch since some of the components were connected by it reference. But, I'll give it a try. Thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

What about Events? If you click on one item of the red list it will `$emit` the value of your `$ref` to your playground thats listening to that type of event.